# Blocking the addObject message of spring ModelAndView object in the jsp on clicking the back button

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, controller

I am displaying the success message in the jsp page that was added to the ModelAndView object in my spring controller. I am successfully able to do it. However, the message gets displayed even after if I go to some other link and click on back button. I just wonder how this message can be displayed only when it is relevant and not when back button is clicked. I use the following code to display in the jsp:

```
<c:if test="${param.successmsg != null}">
    <c:out value="${param.successmsg}"></c:out>
</c:if>
```

and my way of adding the object in the controller is:

```
ModelAndView delmav = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("view.htm"));
String sucmsg="Deleted successfully";
delmav.addObject("successmsg", sucmsg);
return delmav;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the same controller method, then you could check if the delmav already contains the "successmsg", and if it does then remove it and dont display it -

```
ModelAndView delmav = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("view.htm"));
ModelMap delModelMap = delmav.getModelMap();
if ( delModelMap.containsAttribute("successmsg") ) {
   // remove from scope
   Map<String,Object> delModel = delmav.getModel();
   delModel.remove("successmsg");
} else {
   String sucmsg="Deleted successfully";
   delmav.addObject("successmsg", sucmsg);
}
return delmav;
```

Another option is FlashMaps - these are temporary messages for redirects -

```
public String addMyObject(@ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successmsg", "Successfully added..");

    return "redirect:mydirect";

}
```

myredirect.jsp -

```
Access Message - ${successmsg}
```